# aadsts50011: the reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: 'App id'. localhost configuration

Tags: django, azure, backend, django-authentication

I Followed [this](https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) document for setting up the Microsoft Auth system by stuck up with error aadsts50011 ([here is azure portal URI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEIBn.png))
([here is my settings.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QMPZ.png))
([here is django admin portal site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Vge.png))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app redirects away to `login.microsoftonline.com` you can copy the URL and look at the query parameters. One of those will be the `redirect_uri`. That should match what you have configured in the app registration.

Comment: for localhost how should I configure that???? I change default Example.com to localhost but stuck in that

Comment: After clicking sign in button and before you provide input the account, you will find the request url.

Comment: should I add whole link with that along with http in my Django admin sites page?

Comment: copy paste the same url i.e on Azure portal and on django admin site  but nothing  changed

Comment: Paste the value of redirect_uri parameter to redirect Uri's of the app. Same as you have added other two uri's as shown in the image

Comment: I have added some more info